# Autoscaling an SVG embedded in HTML on window resize

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to embed some SVG in an HTML page in a way such that is is automatically resized (using SVG, CSS, or JS) when the page is resized, while still preserving the original aspect ratio.

For example, using an example from W3Schools:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to set the SVG width = 5% of the window width, and have the height scaled proportionately?

I've tried a couple things including `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` and setting the dimensions to 100% within a `<div>` container, but haven't gotten it working yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a `viewBox`-attribute on your SVG root element, which will define the overall size of the SVG-image:

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 185">
```

Now you can set the width OR height of the image via CSS and it will scale perfectly.

Comment: That did the trick. Do you know how the last two parameters for the viewBox are handled? Increasing them seems to *decrease* the size of the image.

Comment: Those numbers are the used width and height of your image. In your example from above it would circle+radius: cx+r=width (140) and cy+r=height (90). Your best choice would to save the image via a graphics software like Inkscape, which will compute the overall sizes and write the viewBox-attribute into the file. If using Inkscape, make sure you select "Optimized Inkscape SVG", which will result in a much smaller file-size and understandable XML source code.

Comment: This answer just saved my day!