# How to rescaling svg element

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, responsive-design, viewport

I'm starting with D3.js and creating a very basic figures. The question is about the width of the `<svg>` tag. How can I adapt the svg width when the user change the window size? It's about make a responsive svg...

I underestand that the viewport of svg delimite the zone where to paint de figures, but when I assign to the `viewport="0 0 100% 100%"` it doesn't work like I would.

I've the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <h3>Graph title</h3>
    <div class="graph">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, h3 {
    position: relative;
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
}

#main {
    position: relative; 
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.graph{position: relative;}

svg {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I think is something about css... Here you have the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/P2eYK/) example with some data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381784/autoscaling-an-svg-embedded-in-html-on-window-resize

Comment: awww man... I've been surfing on StackOverflow and I've not seen anything... I'm retarded. Thks man! :)

Comment: Mostly the general search engines (Google, Yahoo, Bing, DuckDuckGo) will also find the results inside StackOverflow. So it's mostly easier to just search the whole web, and the SO results will just pop up between them ;)

Comment: @newpatriks Please either answer your own question or close this question as a duplicate.